# No data is beilng persisted in JPA/Hibernate/mySql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, java-ee-6

I'm trying to persist form data in database in JPA. It seems, it's getting data from front end to servlet but failing to go through 
service class and therefore no data is beilng persisted in database. Database is in mysql and JPA provider is hibernate.
Table has an AUTO_INCREMENT id as primary key. The error says, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence. But, added the hibernate-jpa-api. Any suggestion is much appreciated. Here is my code:

**servlet:**

```
@WebServlet("/Reservations")
public class Reservations extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            if( request != null) {

                Enumeration<String> names = request.getParameterNames();
                while(names.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String name = names.nextElement();
                    System.out.println(name + " : " + request.getParameter(name));
                }

                String pickUpDate = request.getParameter("pickUpDate");
                Integer totalPass = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("totalPass"));                

                ReservationEntity reservation = new ReservationEntity(pickUpDate, totalPass);
                ReservationSevice reservationSevice = new ReservationSevice();
                reservationSevice.createReservation(reservation);
            }else{
                System.out.println("#############Request is null#########");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception occured");
        }
    }
}
```

**Entity class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reservations_db")
public class ReservationEntity { 
    @Column(name = "pickUpDate")
    private String pickUpDate;

    @Column(name = "totalPass")
    private Integer totalPass;

    public ReservationEntity() 
    {       
    }

    public ReservationEntity(String pickUpDate, Integer totalPass) 
    {
        this.setPickUpDate(pickUpDate);
        this.setTotalPass(totalPass);

    }

    public String getPickUpDate() {
        return pickUpDate;
    }
    public void setPickUpDate(String pickUpDate) {
        this.pickUpDate = pickUpDate;
    }

    public Integer getTotalPass() {
        return totalPass;
    }
    public void setTotalPass(Integer totalPass) {
        this.totalPass = totalPass;
    }
}
```

**Service class for JPA persistence:**

```
public class ReservationSevice 
{
    static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ReservationsPU");
    private static EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); 

    public void createReservation (ReservationEntity reservation)
    {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(reservation);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

**persistence.xml:**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="ReservationsPU">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**error:**

```
Dec 06, 2016 12:19:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.welcomelimo.controller.Reservations] in context with path [/WelcomeLimoUsa] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at com.welcomelimo.service.ReservationSevice.<clinit>(ReservationSevice.java:11)
    at com.welcomelimo.controller.Reservations.doPost(Reservations.java:56)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2508)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2497)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Where did you add the jar? How do you deploy your app? Side note: your entity is invalid: it doesn't have any ID.

Comment: cant get clearer than ClassNotFoundException ...

Comment: JBNizet, I added the jar in Libraries folder in eclipse. The jar for Persistence class is hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar. I added the ID in the entity class with setter and getter but still no luck: @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private int id; Though I'm not sure, do I really need setter and getter methods because id is auto incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Verify, are you passing data source name while getting EntityManagerFactory object.

As given in below code.

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
                        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(DATA_SOURCE_NAME);

                        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
                        properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.NON_JTA_DATASOURCE, ds);
                        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
                                PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, properties);
```